How to properly position child element to its parent?
I was trying to get a better understanding of how kivy parent/child positioning works SPECIFICALLY with the FloatLayout because it allows to place elements based on window size and therefore super dynamic.
This code below is simple. I'm just trying to get label to base ITS position from its parent position, and adjust from there (hence the +200 and +20).
FloatLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'Home'
        size_hint: 1, .2
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'top':1}
    
    Label:
        text: 'Welcome'
        # size_hint: 1, .2
        pos_hint: self.parent.x + 200, self.parent.y + 20

Result image:

My EXPECTATION was for the text "Welcome" to "start" bottom left since this link states "The coordinate system in kivy works from the bottom left! This will be important when placing our objects. (i.e (0, 0) is the bottom left)." so the bottom left of the bottom is first taken into consideration. Then the +200 would move it somewhat to the right, and +20 would move it barely upwards. But the result is clearly different.
Apologies in advance if I'm missing something obvious, I'm still learning. Very grateful for any help. Thank you.
Update
I ran the code:
FloatLayout:
Button:
    text: 'Home'
    size_hint: 1, .2
    pos_hint: {'x':0, 'top':1}
    
    
    Label:
        text: 'Welcome'
        size: self.parent.size
        center: self.parent.x + 200, self.parent.y + 20

And it worked. The text is adjusting properly when I adjust the window size on both x and y axis. But, this seems limiting. What if I wanted to change the size of the label? What if i DIDN'T want to use the 'center' attribute (because pos_hint seems more reasonable to me)? I'm not entirely sure if this is a proper solution, hence why I didn't answer my own question with it.

The pos_hint value is expected to be a dictionary with values as fractions (See the documentation). Your use for the Button is correct, but your use for the Label is not. First, the pos_hint must be a dictionary. If you want to position the Label to the specific coordinates you show, just change pos_hint to pos.

Makes sense, but 2 issues: 1) pos_hint is now "pos_hint: {'x':0.2, 'y':0.2}", for dictionary format. But it's stuck in the bottom left. No change occurs despite changing x an y. 2) I tried your 2nd suggestion with "pos: self.parent.x + 200, self.parent.y + 20". The text adjusts when I move the window vertically but not horizontally. Which, kind of defeats the point of the float layout being able to make sure elements change WITH it.
